# Enabling Do Not Track

Tags: java, google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver

Is there a way to enable the "[Do not track](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/2790761?hl=en)" option for [selenium](http://www.seleniumhq.org/download/) using chromedriver?

None of the [command line switches](http://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/) seem to help and [this](http://www.whatismybrowser.com/is-do-not-track-enabled) website says that the option is disabled when run with chromedriver even though my regular Chrome profile has it turned on. I want to use a temporary profile and not load my existing one though.

Suggestions? Can the option be set automatically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out. It can be done by setting the preferences from the [Chrome preferences file](http://www.chromium.org/administrators/configuring-other-preferences) like this:

```
Map<String, Object> preferences = new HashMap<String, Object>();
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();

preferences.put("enable_do_not_track", true);
options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", preferences);
```

Answer (score 3):

For those working with the Python, we were able to follow the Java answer above and do the following:

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
prefs = {"enable_do_not_track": True}
options.add_experimental_option("prefs", prefs)
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: In that case, perhaps it would have been better to add it as a comment to the accepted answer? My apologies; I'm new here :) This was meant to add the python implementation of the accepted answer since that's what I was looking for when I found this post. @Elletlar

Comment: You can press edit on your answer to supply more info. But in general try to avoid code only answers...Cheers!.

Comment: Thanks, appreciate the input!

Answer (score 0):

@pynterest's [answer above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51733489/2187161) works in Python. For those of you who wish to confirm this try:

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
no_track = {"enable_do_not_track": True}
options.add_experimental_option("prefs", no_track)
b = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
b.get('https://www.whatismybrowser.com/detect/is-do-not-track-enabled')
```

Which should open up a selenium browser telling you that Do Not Track is enabled.